# Slogan 社会……方何 on a Maoist poster

Tags: phrase, expressions, culture

What is the slogan, mostly obscured by the typist, on the poster that hangs behind him, on [this](https://maoeraobjects.ac.uk/sources/typewriters-mao-propaganda-poster/) poster from 1956?

Since the artist chose to obscure the poster, it must have been easily recognizable at the time; but [this](http://www.commonprogram.science/poster.html) massive list of Chinese posters doesn't have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the poster is this one:

[image]

the propaganda is “社會主義是我們的目標，是我們的方向”, most characters are in simplified chinese.

the meaning is, roughly: “socialism is our target, is our direction”

Comment: It is not exactly Simplified Chinese we use now. See "們", it is Traditional Chinese.

Comment: well, i’ll check info about the creation date of this poster, and the “official” simplified characters available at that time. meanwhile, i edited the answer. thanks for mention it 